# Improve of measurability on limit.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider a measure space $(X, \mathcal{A}, P)$ and a function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ measurable (using the Borel $\sigma$-algrebra on $\mathbb{R}$).

In some cases is possible to modify $f$ on a negligible set, and obtain a function that is measurable with respect to a smaller $\sigma$-algebra, for example, let $f$ be such that $f(x) = 0$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 1$, then using Lebesgue measure the function $f$ can be modified to $f(x) = 0$ for all  $x$ but this is now measurable with respect to $\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$ instead of the original $\{\emptyset, \{0\}, (\infty, 0), (0, \infty), \mathbb{R}\}$.

What is the name of this property?

I'm interested in this happening in limits: Let $(X, \mathcal{X}, P)$ be a probability space with a sub $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{Y} \subset \mathcal{X}$: Consider a $\mathcal{X}$-measurable function $f$ and a sequence of $\mathcal{Y}$-measurable functions $f_n$ so that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_A f_n(x) P(dx) = \int_A f(x) P(dx)$$ for any $A \in \mathcal{X}$.

Is it true that $f$ is actually $\mathcal{Y}$-measurable? I guess this is not true in general, but is it possible to modify$f$ on a $P$-negligible to obtain a $\mathcal{Y}$ measurable function?

I have actually that $\mathcal{Y}=\sigma(\rho)$ then Doob-Dynkin should help somehow, but I can't see how exactly.

Thanks.

Comment: For which $A$ the convergence is supposed to hold?

Comment: Thanks, i just fixed that it should be for any $A \in \mathcal{X}$.

Comment: In the case of strong convergence the result is true passing by Cauchy sequences and completeness of the $L^1$ space with respect of both measures. If the convergence above implies weak convergence in $L^1$ then by Mazur's lemma we have a strongly convergent sequence formed by finite convex sum. I guess that the main ideas will be hidden in the completeness of the L^p spaces and the relation between closed and convex set in the strong and weak topology in locally convex spaces, I guess I need to add some extra conditions.